# Desktop Shortcut for MS Word office-js addin?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

Is it possible to create a desktop shortcut for a MS Word Office-JS add-in?

Documentation does not have anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is not possible. An Office add-in can only open in the context of an open Office document.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Office web add-ins are just web applications loaded by the embedded web browsers (or standalone in case of Office on the web). They are not designed for running like a standalone application and depend on the `OfficeJS` library.